# Using JMS in RESTFull Web services

Tags: java, asynchronous, jms, spring-jms

I am developing the **Rest Full** services in **Java+Spring**, that can be used by Mobile Apps(iPhone+Android) and on Web Applications.

Would it be better choice to choose **JMS(Java Messasing service)** for Sending asynchronous and Reliable Email messages to Mobile Apps and Web application or is there any better alternative other than JMS for **asynchronous** messaging. Please help.

**EDIT :**

I want my RESTFull web services to send email messages that not only provide the guarantee of delivery of the Email messages but also  use the asyancronous messaging mode so that server would not be waiting for reciever to recieve the message. Also please suggest if i use JMS  at server end to Publish/Produce the messages in a Queue, how will the Mobile Apps will recieve the messages from the JMS Queue? Is it possible for IPhone/Android/PHP web application to recieve the message that was published by JAVA server.

Thanks,

Arun Kumar

Comment: There are tons of alternatives to JMS for asynchronous messaging. You question doesn't explain your requirements, difficult to suggest anything specific. Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

JMS isn't appropriate for mobile applications. Mobile applications can't be expected to be always running and listening for connections. For these reasons [Push Notifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) are used for sending messages to mobile devices. Both Apple and Google offer this kind of services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible for a PHP web application to receive the message that was published by JAVA server using JMS.

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you could post this a separate question.